# не получается добавить запись со ссылкой на другую запись в Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть две модели: `platform` и `place` (*платформа и место на платформе*).

**platform**

```
{
  name: {
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    type: String,
    empty: false
  },
  description: {
    required: false,
    type: String,
    empty: true
  }
}
```

**place**

```
{
  name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    empty: false
  },
  platform: new Mongoose.Schema({
    type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: PlatformSchema
  })
}
```

У платформы имя должно быть уникальным. Генерирую список платформ, затем пытаюсь сгенерировать список мест на платформах. Но получаю ошибку

```
WriteError({
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 1,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.places index: platform.ref.name_1 dup key: { : null }",
  "op": {
    "_id": "5b7ea477798f9c41f81c0234",
    "name": "top",
    "platform": {
      "_id":"5b7ea41b878b4a41abcfc952"
    }
  }
})
```

Получаю её до тех пор, пока не выпилю индекс уникальности `platform.name`.

Добавлять `place` пытаюсь по разному:

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: platformDocumentInstance
  }
])
```

или

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: platformDocumentInstance._id
  }
])
```

или

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: {
      _id: platformDocumentInstance._id,
      name: platformDocumentInstance.name
    }
  }
])
```

безполезно, результат один и тот же. Первый `place` создаётся нормально, со ссылкой на `platform`. Следующее добавление генерирует выше приведённую ошибку. Видимо при первом добавлении `place` значение индекса `platform.ref.name_1` забивается `null`ом. При добавлении следующего `place`а срабатывает ограничение уникальности, т.к. `null` уже есть.
Что с этим делать... вообще не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема в объявлении схемы для свойства `platform` схемы `place`. Я объявляю с использованием `new Mongoose.Schema(...)`, а нужно просто объявить объект, как и для любого другого поля `{...}`